# How to show list of files with cyrillic name only?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

How do I can see in my directory, list of files, that have a Cyrillic name by using terminal, awk, and other stuff? If I'm trying all Russian symbols in find, it's like make terminal broken or stuff.

not sure what example I need to give. I need to see a list of files, that name is written via Cyrillic symbols. 
what I tried? I tried "find" and use all buttons on Russian keyboard like "й ц у к е н г ш щ з х ъ ф  ы в а п р о  д ж э я ч с м и т ь б ю" and when I wrote it like "й","ц" it doesn't work. But I don't think its a problem because I made it just because I don't know how to chose only Cyrillic symbols. And it doesn't matter if it will show also Ukranian names or Belarus, or any else Cyrillic, so I want to ask how to show a list of Cyrillic names of files in my directory.

Comment: It would help enormously if you could paste an example of your problem, and the commands you're trying, into the question.

Comment: Please share a file with Cyrillic name, so people can try to figure out how to solve it

Comment: How can I share file here? 
If u need name example it can be "клиенты.txt" or anything else.

Comment: actually, I also need to see directories inside of my directory that also use Cyrillic symbols in the name (only in name, not the text inside .txt or smth). But it's also still doesn't really matter because in my system I have no Cyrillic files, but I need to find a command that can show me, that I don't have any of this files for real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all files in the current directory that contains Russian characters in their names:

```
find . -type f -name "[А-Яа-яЁё]*"
```